# Orientdb : Traversal not producing correct output

Tags: orientdb, traversal, graph-databases

Can anybody tell me how to get all nodes and edges in a traversal?

For example, if I run the following query:

```
select from (TRAVERSE in(), inE() FROM (SELECT FROM Example_Class WHERE @rid = #13:187))
```

the result changes every time.

Requirement: Get all unordered nodes and edges from a specific node (#13:187 in the example above).

Comment: hi, i'm not shure to understand your requirement, could you add a graphical example? tnx

Comment: you can find info on traversal here http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Java-Traverse.html#traversing-strategies

Comment: Thanks Ivan, solved the issue anyways.

Answer (score 0):

One way to retrieve the edges and nodes encountered while traversing a graph from a particular node, say NODE, is using the query:

```
> traverse outE(), inV() from NODE
```

Here is an example.  First, let's just run out() to retrieve the encountered nodes (here the start (#11:11) and end (#11:15)); the resultant rows give the edge information:

```
> traverse out() from #11:11

----+------+------+-----+-------+-------
#   |@RID  |@CLASS|label|in_E3  |out_E3 
----+------+------+-----+-------+-------
0   |#11:11|Circle|4    |[#15:2]|[#15:4]
1   |#11:15|Circle|8    |[#15:4]|null   
----+------+------+-----+-------+-------
```

Here the picture is:  (#11:11) -[#15:4]> (#11:15)

Now let's formulate the query so that the rows of the result-set include both nodes and edges:

```
> traverse outE(), inV() from #11:11

----+------+------+-----+-------+-------+------+------
#   |@RID  |@CLASS|label|in_E3  |out_E3 |in    |out   
----+------+------+-----+-------+-------+------+------
0   |#11:11|Circle|4    |[#15:2]|[#15:4]|null  |null  
1   |#15:4 |E3    |4>8  |null   |null   |#11:15|#11:11
2   |#11:15|Circle|8    |[#15:4]|null   |null  |null  
----+------+------+-----+-------+-------+------+------
```